# The last of the getParcelableArrayList element appears as empty string

Tags: android, arraylist, parcelable

When I put the parcelable arraylist in the bundle and get it with `getParcelableArrayList`, all elements are showing correctly, while the last element is showing as empty string.

**My custom Parcelable item:**

```
public class Media implements Parcelable {

    private final Uri uri;
    private Type type;
    private InfoModel infoModel;

    public Media(Uri uri, Type type) {
     
        this.uri = uri;
        this.type = type;
        this.infoModel = InfoModel.empty();
    }

    public Media() {
        this.uri = null;
        this.type = Type.image;
        this.infoModel = InfoModel.empty();
    }

    protected Media(Parcel in) {
        uri = in.readParcelable(Uri.class.getClassLoader());
        type = Type.valueOf(in.readString());
        infoModel = in.readParcelable(InfoModel.class.getClassLoader());
    }

    public void setInfoModel(InfoModel infoModel) {
        this.infoModel = infoModel;
    }

    public InfoModel getInfoModel() {
        return infoModel;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeParcelable(uri, flags);
        dest.writeString(this.type.name());
        dest.writeParcelable(infoModel, flags);
    }

    public static final Creator<Media> CREATOR = new Creator<Media>() {
        @Override
        public Media createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Media(in);
        }

        @Override
        public Media[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Media[size];
        }
    };

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Media media = (Media) o;

        return uri.equals(media.uri);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return uri.hashCode();
    }
}
```

**When I check the media list in bundle, I see there is no problem -> bundleIntent function:**

```
public class ShowMediaActivity extends Activity {

    public static Intent buildIntent(@NonNull ArrayList<Media> medias) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, ShowMediaActivity.class);
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putParcelableArrayList(KEY_MEDIA, medias);
            intent.putExtra("bundle", b);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            return intent;
        }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Logger.i();
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_container);

        Bundle b = getIntent().getBundleExtra("bundle");
        List<Media> initialMedia = new ArrayList<>();
        if (b != null) {
            initialMedia = b.getParcelableArrayList(KEY_MEDIA);
        }

     }
```

**initialMedia elements in onCreate:**

> initialMedia has 1 elements : Media

> initialMedia has 2 elements : Media, ""

> initialMedia has 3 elements : Media, Media, ""

> initialMedia has 4 elements : Media, Media, Media, ""

Comment: Didi you verified in RUNTIME if the last element is really a String or you just verify it using IDE Inspector during debugging? Sometimes the Inspector shows wrong values (rare but it occurs sometimes). Try printing in LogCat something similar to "Log.d(TAG, List[n].class.getName())"

Comment: I tried it in debug. I also tried logcat, it gave the same result.

Comment: So the last element's Class is "java.lang.String" instead of a previous ones "a.b.Media"?

Comment: Just like you said

Comment: I just copy/pasted your code and simulated it. It workings as expected retrieving a correct "initialMedia" variable. Maybe you have other things that adds/inserts items (maybe by reflection) in that Array. It's not possibile to have an ArrayList with these inhomogeneous items inside it. String isn't a Parcelable and cannot be normally inserted/added in an ArrayList of Parcelables.

Comment: The thread where I set the media is different, the thread I read is different. Could this be due to

Comment: I bought both in the same thread, it didn't work :(

Comment: It's not possibile to help you more than this without a compilable/testing code. I copy/pasted your code and it works on my Android Studio and my devices, so the "guilty" piece of code it's not there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I left an item that I converted to long in InfoModel class in `in.readInt()` instead of `in.readLong()`. I was not aware of it at all. Thank you for your help @emandt

```
    public InfoModel(Parcel in) {
        startTime = in.readLong();
        endTime = in.readLong();
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeLong(startTime);
        dest.writeLong(endTime);
    }
```